# sorting by comparing line

Tags: java, sorting

This data is saved in data.txt I am trying to write a program that can arrange

```
18b0885  // this is the registration number, 
   SS844 Parallel Algorithms        //  These are course taken by student
   SS555 Calculus for Distributed Computing
   SS501 Quantum Communication

17b0585
   SS828 Problem Based Programming
   SS660 Genetic Computation
   SS567 Hacking Quantum Network

17b2582
   SS567 Hacking Quantum Network
   SS876 Positronics
   SS880 Quark-based Logic
```

following program shorts by registration number.

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.FileReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Collections;
import java.util.Comparator;
import java.util.List;

public class Sorter {

    static List<Data> read() throws FileNotFoundException, IOException {
        BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("data.txt"));
        List<Data> list = new ArrayList<>();
        String line;
        Data data = null;
        while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
            if (line.matches("\\s*")) {
                continue; // skip blank lines
            }
            // Assume line that begins with space is a course.
            if (Character.isSpaceChar(line.charAt(0))) {
                //  Add new course to data if it's there.
                if (data == null) {
                    System.err.println("Missing serial for course " + line);
                } else {
                    data.courses.add(line);
                }
            } else {
                // Add completed data to list if there is one.
                if (data != null) {
                    list.add(data);
                }
                // Make new data with this serial.
                data = new Data(line);
            }
        }
        // Add the last data to the list if there is one.
        if (data != null) {
            list.add(data);
        }
        return list;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        try {
            // Read.
            List<Data> list = read();

            // Sort based on serials.
            Collections.sort(list, new Comparator<Data>() {
                @Override
                public int compare(Data a, Data b) {
                    return a.serial.compareTo(b.serial);
                }
            });

            // Print.
            for (Data data : list) {
                data.print();
            }
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            System.err.println("Read failed.");
        }
    }
}

// Local class to hold data: a serial and related courses.
class Data {

    String serial;
    List<String> courses;

    Data(String serial) {
        this.serial = serial;
        courses = new ArrayList<>();
    }

    void print() {
        System.out.println(serial);
        for (String course : courses) {
            System.out.println(course);
        }
    }
}
```

### output from the program is following

```
17b2582
   SS567 Hacking Quantum Network
   SS876 Positronics
   SS880 Quark-based Logic

17b0585
   SS828 Problem Based Programming
   SS660 Genetic Computation
   SS567 Hacking Quantum Network

18b0885  
   SS844 Parallel Algorithms       
   SS555 Calculus for Distributed Computing
   SS501 Quantum Communication
```

---

Wanted output is like following.

```
SS501 Quantum Communication
     18b0885
     17b2582

SS567 Hacking Quantum Network
     17b2582
     17b0585

SS844 Parallel Algorithms 
     17b2582
     17b0585
     18b0885
```

I have modified the code and gives output like this

```
    SS501 Quantum Communication
    SS555 Calculus for Distributed Computing
    SS567 Hacking Quantum Network
    SS567 Hacking Quantum Network
    SS660 Genetic Computation
    SS828 Problem Based Programming
    SS844 Parallel Algorithms
    SS876 Positronics
    SS880 Quark-based Logic

    17b2582
    17b0585
    18b0885
```

Comment: You haven't actually asked a question - nor explained *how* you've modified the code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can simply use a `Map` based implementation, IMHO code would be much simpler and `map` is directly fitting in your requirement:

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.FileReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Map;
import java.util.Map.Entry;
import java.util.Set;

public class Sorter {

    static Map<String, List<String>> read() throws FileNotFoundException,
            IOException {
        BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("data.txt"));
        String line;
        Map<String, List<String>> map = new HashMap<String, List<String>>();
        String value = "";
        while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
            if (line.matches("\\s*")) {
                continue; // skip blank lines
            }
            // Assume line that begins with space is a course.
            if (Character.isSpaceChar(line.charAt(0))) {
                // Add new course to data if it's there.
                if (!map.containsKey(line)) {
                    map.put(line, new ArrayList<String>());
                }
                map.get(line).add(value);
            } else {
                // Add completed data to list if there is one.
                value = line;
            }
        }
        return map;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        try {
            Map<String, List<String>> list = read();
            Set<Entry<String, List<String>>> set = list.entrySet();
            for (Entry<String, List<String>> e : set) {
                System.out.println(e.getKey());
                for (String s : e.getValue()) {
                    System.out.println("\t" + s);
                }
            }
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            System.err.println("Read failed.");
        }
    }
}
```

Sample Output based on posted input data.txt should be:

```
SS828 Problem Based Programming
    17b0585
   SS555 Calculus for Distributed Computing
    18b0885  
   SS844 Parallel Algorithms        
    18b0885  
   SS876 Positronics
    17b2582
   SS660 Genetic Computation
    17b0585
   SS567 Hacking Quantum Network
    17b0585
    17b2582
   SS880 Quark-based Logic
    17b2582
   SS501 Quantum Communication
    18b0885
```

Comment: compiled and get an error Class Entry cannot be found. how to fix this?

Comment: Can you update the full code Here. I haven't used Entry before.

Comment: if I want to arrange in ascending order by course code eg "SS828" come s before SS844, SS876 and so on, course name follows code. should I break the List?

Comment: It's straightforward, change `HashMap` to `TreeMap` and you would see sorted courses in ascending order..